# Unable to retrieve price information from a Magento product collection

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to output products from some category on an arbitrary page in a fashion similar to that of list.phtml's grid format.

I have the following snippet:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->load(17);
$_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection()
                               ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
```

That gives me a product collection which I then iterate over with:

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 

<!-- This works -->
<h2 class="product-name">
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
    </a>
</h2>

<!-- This does not -->
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>

<!-- This just returns out of stock -->
<div class="actions">
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
            <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
        </button>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>                                                    
</div>

endforeach;
```

The above code except for the call to get the product collection at the top is just borrowed from list.phtml.

Can anyone tell me why the price and is saleable information is not available, hence why the item appears out of stock? Previously when the product name was unavailable, I had to add `->addAttributeToSelect('name')`, would I need to add something along those lines?

Comment: Dude Have you tried it without `addAttributeToSelect` method. I think ProductCollection gives all basic Attributes. If not Then I am afraid you have to do `addAttributeToSelect` to every attribute that you need.

Comment: @SAM Yeah, tried ->addAttributeToSelect('price') / ->addAttributeToSelect('inventory') / ->addAttributeToSelect('saleable') but they were just stabs in the dark. Can't find the documentation that refers to those calls either...

Comment: One thing that you can cross check. Your Phtml must be the instance of `catalog/product_list` class & you must use `$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();` method of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_list` class.
If that also don't work then I'd recommend Mimic a class in you local module like `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_list` and then there u can customize the Collection loading as per your needs. This is something I have done in past. So it must work. Hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the code below in your phtml file.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
$productBlock=$this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product");
foreach($_productCollection  as $_product)
{
    //for get the price of product 
    if($_product->isSaleable()) //this will check if product is in stock
       echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product,true);
}
```

Comment: just an advice - you should **NEVER** load products in the loop, especially if you already have the product collection; you should just include the data you need into the collection; also `new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` is also wrong way to instantiate a block instance from Magento's perspective - Magento uses Factory pattern to create Models, Blocks and Helpers objects

Comment: @SlayerBirden Thanks, could you suggest how I'd include the pricing data? My loop is just the standard code in the <ul> from list.phtml put on my homepage. It must exist in the product collection list.phtml, but I can't seem to recreate the same model of data in my call to get the collection at the top of my code.

Comment: @Slayer Birden..Thanks for figure out my mistakes. I have edited my code.

Comment: Hi, this works. Does this solution have the problem pointed out by @SlayerBirden in that using ->createBlock("catalog/product") recursively could be problematic? Thanks

Comment: the code looks good, but @RodgersandHammertime is right - it's better to instantiate block just once - outside of the loop: `$catalogBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product");`, and then use it's method inside the loop `$catalogBlock->getPriceHtml()`

Comment: @SlayerBirden Excellent! Thank you, that wraps everything up neatly. And, of course, thank you Anant Shukla very much too.

Answer (score 2):

So you're on the right path to look into core, if you want to copy some functional that is similar to the one from the basic Magento - like product listing.

1. the price function `getPriceHtml` is a method defined in the abstract class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`. So to use it, you need to extend your block from the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` one.
2. `isSaleable` returned false because you didn't have some of the attributes joined to your collection.

Here's how you should accomplish your goal, if you want to follow Magento's logic.

1. Create your own module, or just block in `local/Mage/Catalog/Block/YourBlock.php`. This block should extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`. After that create a method in this block `getCustomProductCollection()`:

   ```
   pubcli funciton getCustomProductCollection()
   {
       if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
           $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(17);
           $layer = $this->getLayer();
           $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
           $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
       }
       return $this->_productCollection;
   }
   ```
2. Now in your `phtml` file you'll just call for this method:

   ```
   $productCollection = $this->getCustomProductCollection();
   ```

And the rest of the code will work.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Do I need to reference the newly created block some how? I have created the block and made it extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract but the result is the same, and when I var_dump() the newly created $productCollection, it is returned as null?

Answer (score 0):

```
$productBlock=$this->getLayout()->createBlock("catalog/product");
echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product,true);
```

Try this